# How to create loop through moving an array over 2 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

i have name:value pairs in the range RA1:RB21 that I want to 2 columns over.  I need to repeat the process 480 times but I'm struggling with how to create a loop to move over 2 columns.

See below for what I'm doing manually.  Yes I've tried Googling and searching stack overflow but the results are moving a row or moving a single column.  I'm pretty sure I can use MoveColumns but struggling with how to create a loop with this array.  Appreciate any help or direction.

Note I'm using the {contentsonly: true} flag but its not necessary.

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("some cool sheet");
    sheet.getRange("RY2:RZ21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("SA2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RW2:RX21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RY2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RU2:RV21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RW2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RS2:RT21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RU2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RQ2:RR21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RS2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RO2:RP21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RQ2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RM2:RN21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RO2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RK2:RL21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RM2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RI2:RJ21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RK2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RG2:RH21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RI2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RE2:RF21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RG2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RC2:RD21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RE2"), {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.getRange("RA2:RB21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RC2"), {contentsOnly: true});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 480 times?  Are you only showing a portion of the columns you want to move?

Comment: Why not just do it this way: `sheet.getRange("RA2:RZ21").copyTo(sheet.getRange("RC2"),, {contentsOnly: true})`

Comment: Or `const vs = sheet.getRange("RA2:RZ21").getValues()
    sheet.getRange(2,469,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);`